# Can I select nuget packages that will be installed automatically every time I create a new script?

Tags: linqpad

There are a few packages that I install 95% of the time I write any scripts in Linqpad. For instance, JSON.net, is a nuget package I install every single time, and RestSharp is a close second. So my question is, is there a way to set up Linqpad to install these nuget packages by default? If not, is there a way to add them to a collection so that they can easily be installed every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

- Add these packages to the **My Extensions** query (then they'll be implicitly referenced by all queries)
- Add these packages to any query, and press **Set as default for new queries**

Yet another option is via a code snippet. Right-click the editor and choose **Create Code Snippet**, then click the **References** checkbox to add the NuGet package. Whatever you name the snippet becomes a shortcut to add the package, so if you name the snippet *json*, you just type `json` followed by the tab key, and it will add the package.